# enumerate python using different start values

Tags: python, excel, enumeration, gspread

```
for index, value in enumerate(array_seller_name, start= 1):
sheet.update_cell(index, 1, array_seller_name[index])
```

I'm trying to update google sheet with values from array.
My problem is that index in google sheet has to start from 2 and index used to extract values from array from 0.
Is there anyway to use different values in enumarate? Should i use different approach altogether?

Comment: Can you just assign the index value to a variable and add two where required? E.g. `x = 0`; use `x` when enumerating the array and `x + 2` when updating the sheet?

Comment: Thanks, i've done [index-2], work's great.